# Unable to get values after decimal after evaluating spring expressions

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I am trying to do a following thing:

```
String value = "10/3"; 
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
final Expression expression = parser.parseExpression(value);
System.out.println("value1: "+expression.getValue(Double.class));
System.out.println("value2: "+expression.getValue());
```

output:

```
value1: 3.0
value2: 3
```

I am unable to get values after decimal. The above value can be any mathematical expression like `(3/4*5+10)` so I cannot read this string.

Comment: sorry i dont think so regex tag is needed for this

Comment: Perhaps it is parsed like Java, where `double d = 10/3` is also `3`, because `10/3` is interpreted as integer division? Try `String value="10.0/3";`

Comment: ya this will work but problem is input that would be coming could be in any format, if i get (10/3) it is failing.

Comment: @TAsk this is not working as i thing it first evaluates (10/3) =3 and then goes for multiplication with 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple matematical expressions like yours, instead of using the SpEL's `ExpressionParser`, you can use the [Java Scripting API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/). There are three steps you need to follow:

1. Create a `ScriptEngineManager` object.
2. Get a `ScriptEngine` object from the manager.
3. Evaluate script using the `ScriptEngine`'s `eval` methods.

For example:

```
import javax.script.*;
public class EvalScript {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        engine.eval("3/4*5 + 10");
    }
}
```

Comment: does this technique has any negatives over the above mentioned i.e spring expressions??

Comment: For expressions like the above one, no. For Spring specific expressions, the JavaScript API won't work

Answer (score 0):

With the value of "10/3" both are integers so integer division is performed. If you want to get a decimal value one of the values needs to be a decimal, such as:

```
String value = "10/3";
```

Complete Example:

```
    String value = "10/3.0";
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    final Expression expression = parser.parseExpression(value);
    System.out.println("value1: "+expression.getValue(Double.class));
    System.out.println("value2: "+expression.getValue());
```

Output:

> ```
> value1: 3.3333333333333335
> value2: 3.3333333333333335
> ```